# how install a new ourdoor digital aerial

Tags: tv-antenna

I have a problem with the tv aerial. I used a aerial splitter to split the aerial into 2 with one spare way. I'm not getting a signal in a room thats 50 foot away from the splitter. However the room where the splitter is works perfectly. I was told that the digital signal isn't as easy to split as analogue. The best way would be to install a new digital outdoor aerial. Is this true or is he just trying to get business off me?

If this is true / partly true, what tools would I need to fit it properly?
how do I know which direction I should point at? I noticed our is straight whilest the block of flats behind us is at an angle.
Seems that our is pointing more towards theirs.

A tutorial / video would be most helpful too because never ever done this before. Am a trainee electrician not aerial man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's no such thing as a Digital Antenna, the radio wave being intercepted by the antenna doesn't care what it looks like, only that its electrical specs capture the signal. Those fancy cut weird antennas that are made to look digital are just a sales ploy to increase the selling price.
2. You probably need a new antenna with clean connections to the active elements and more gain that the old one you're replacing.
3. Digital TV is very sensitive to signal strength. Passive splitters decrease signal strength, long cable runs reduce signal strength. If you're going to have long cable runs, use a distribution amplifier instead of a passive splitter and use low-loss quad-shielded RG-6 for all your runs to reduce signal loss both before and after the amplifier.

Comment: So is there any aerials I can fit two cables to? The ones I saw today at screwfix had one F connector.

Comment: I take it your TV has an F connector and another connection with two screws (separate VHF and UHF inputs)? Most modern televisions have combined the UHF and VHF tuner so there's only one cable connection. For this you use a combined VHF/UHF antenna.

Comment: no I want to split the connection to two rooms. So could I just use a masthead amp? http://www.screwfix.com/p/labgear-screened-masthead-amp-2-way-9db/57882# yes?

Comment: Yep, masthead amp down to a two way splitter and see if the signal is enough at both TV's. Still if you have a considerable run, you may still need a distribution amp instead of the splitter.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with points 1 & 3 of Fiasco Labs' answer.

Before replacing the antenna, I would try the following.

1) Mark the current position of the antenna, and find the signal strength display on your TV set (or digital adaptor box) and note the reading and channel you take the reading from.

2) Try orienting the antenna similar to others that are nearby.   Does that improve the signal strength?   If not, you may want to try a couple other orientations before returning to the original.   Note that different channels may require different orientations for best signal, you will have to find a compromise that works well for all of the channels you want to receive.

3) Check all of the connections to make sure they are clean and the connectors are snug.

4) Replace the 3-way splitter with a 2-way version.  It will have less signal loss than the 3-way model.

5) Check the cable to the distant room for any indication of damage.  Do the connectors look professionally installed?

If none of these help, you may need a larger antenna, a distribution amplifier, or a signal booster.